# how to schedule a tree of jobs using hangfire batching

Tags: c#, hangfire

We need to execute some calculations where the inputs are the outputs of other calculations. This can be modelled as a tree like below:

[image]

Here is the expected behavior, calculation jobs 1 through 6 are scheduled first. When 1, 2, and 3 are done then 7 is scheduled. When 4 is done then 8 is scheduled. When 5 and 6 are done then 9 will be scheduled. 10 will only be scheduled when 7, 8, and 9 are done. 11 waits for 10 and 12 waits for 11.

How would we batch these using the api in hangfire pro?

We are contemplating buying the pro license but we need to confirm it will cover the above use case.